# how to video chat using webRTC

Tags: ios, objective-c, websocket, webrtc

how to make video chat via WebRTC. I have full working back-end (singaling and stun) servers and in browser video chat still working. I want to connect this chat to iOS app without using web view because Safari unsupported webRTC technology. Help me. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the native WebRTC library for iOS: http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/ios get AppRTCDemo running and go from there

Comment: It's worth taking a look at https://github.com/gandg/webrtc-ios

Answer (score 0):

There is a native api part on WebRTC official site :
https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/